# C++ Regarding Reference to a method

Tags: c++

I got a function at

```
File2.cpp which contains the following code below

#include "File2.h"
//some codes in between

static float File2::computeData(string s,int a,int b,float c,float d)
{
float result;
//the compute code
return result;
}
```

at File2.h , i tried to declare it at my class

```
Class File2
{
private:
//some variables
public:
static float computeData(string,int,int,float,float);
};
```

I get an error that say cannot declare member function static float Data::computeData(std::string,int ,int , float , float) to have static linkage [-fpermissive]

then also.. at my

Main.cpp

I was trying to use the function

```
#include "File2.h"

float result;
result = computeData(string s,int a,int b,float c,float d);
```

and it give me computeData was not declared in this scope..

**Sincerely thanks for all helps!**

Answer (score 2):

You only declare `static` member methods as `static` inside the class, not outside. The definition should be:

```
float File2::computeData(string s,int a,int b,float c,float d)
{
   float result;
   //the compute code
   return result;
}
```

No `static` keyword outside the class.

Outside of a class definition, `static` gives internal (or static) linkage, which is not permitted for static member functions:

```
class X
{
    static void foo(); //static class member
};

static void foo();     //static free function w/ internal linkage
```

Answer (score 2):

These are two meanings of `static`.  Declaring a static member function is done in the class definition **only**, and means that the function takes no `this` pointer at runtime (i.e. it's a regular function which happens to have access to private data in class `File2`).  Declaring a function `static` in its definition is the C syntax for `static`, and means that the function is not visible/linkable outside its current file.  In C++, member functions cannot have static linkage.  Don't put `static` in the definition of a static member function.